# Assigning a value to an element of a tuple in Julia

Tags: tuples, julia

I am facing a problem with tuples in Julia. Here is what I am trying to do

```
julia> temp = [1 2 3]
julia> A = tuple(temp, temp)
julia> B = tuple(A,A,A)
```

B looks like this :

```
julia> B
((
[1 2 3],

[1 2 3]),(
[1 2 3],

[1 2 3]),(
[1 2 3],

[1 2 3]))
```

I understand I can access the 'very' first element in B by 
B[1][1][1] which returns 1 (as expected)

But, if I try to assign a particular value to B[1][1][1], say if I do,
`julia> B[1][1][1] = 20`, this is what I get,

```
julia> B
((
[20 2 3],

[20 2 3]),(
[20 2 3],

[20 2 3]),(
[20 2 3],

[20 2 3]))
```

The first elements of all the sub-tuples have been changed. Is there a way to change the value of B[1][1][1] without affecting the other sub-tuples ??

Thanks in advance.

PS : I'm using Julia 0.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not quite a problem with tuples. Exactly the same thing will happen if you use arrays.

`A = (temp, temp)` will reference the same address in memory twice. So you need to do `A = (copy(temp), copy(temp))`

But ...

> copy(x)
>
> Create a shallow copy of x: **the outer structure is copied, but
>   not all internal values**. For example, copying an array produces a new
>   array with identically-same elements as the original.

So for `B = (A, A, A)` we need to use `deepcopy` in order to get the values (rather than the references) of each variable. i.e. `B = (deepcopy(A), deep copy(A), deepcopy(A))`

Check out the docs for `copy` and `deepcopy` here:
http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/#Base.copy

Answer (score 2):

```
A = tuple(temp, temp)
```

You make this a tuple of all the same arrays (note you can just write `A = (temp,temp)`). If you want to use a copy of the array, use `A = (copy(temp),copy(temp))`. The value of an array is its reference, and thus when you do `A = (temp,temp)`, you just have two references to the same slab of memory, which is why when you change one, the other changes.

Comment: I get it, but still, If I want to make a tuple out of the above tuple A, I still face the same issue.
B = (copy(A), copy(A), copy(A)) 
B[1][1][1] = 20 changes the value of the first index of all the sub tuples. 

I only want to change the value in the first index of the first subtuple

Thanks again

Comment: Use `deepcopy` in that case. `copy` copies the values of the collection. A tuple of arrays will copy the value of the arrays. But remember, the value of the array is its reference, and so it will copy over the same reference. `deepcopy` creates a whole new type instance which matches the previous type, so it won't have this problem with nested collections (but is slightly slower, so it shouldn't always be used).

Answer (score -3):

#### Equal sign (a=b)

- simple types are deep copied
- containers of simple types (or other containers) are shadow copied (their internal is only referenced, not copied)

#### copy(x)

- simple types are deep copied
- containers of simple types are deep copied
- containers of containers: the content is shadow copied (the content of the content is only referenced, not copied)

#### deepcopy(x)

- everything is deep copied recursively

Comment: This isn't exactly wrong... because the terminology is meaningless. There is no such thing in Julia as a "simple type". And the functions are not magic: they do the same thing to every type. `a=b` sets the value of `a` to the value of `b`, `copy(a)` makes a new type with the same values for the fields, and `deepcopy(a)` does that copy recursively on each field. The only thing you need to know is that the value of an immutable is its values (fields), whereas the value of a mutable type is its pointer.